# How do I disable the reload dialog in Geany?

Tags: geany

If a file open in geany is modified by another program, and geany is then brought to the front, then geany displays a modal dialog as follows.

```
The file 'stuff.txt' on the disk is more recent than
the current buffer.

Do you want to reload it?
```

This dialog is displayed, blocking any sort of work flow if files are continually regenerated by running command-line tools. How can this behavior be changed so that the dialog does not appear, and geany automatically reloads any such file?

Comment: I don't believe this can be changed, at least I don't see any options anywhere that seem to pertain to this. You might have better luck contacting their mailing list.

Comment: Not true.  See @Shivang Tiwari's answer, and my comment.

Answer (score 3):

Close Geany (else your changes will be overwritten), then open geany.conf in a different editor. Find disk_check_timeout and set it to 0. Save that, and reopen Geany.

Comment: This does not make Geany automatically reload the file, it simply turns off any warning that the file has been changed.

Comment: Whoops, I misread the question. Thought he _didn't_ want to reload.

Comment: Another wrong answer.

Answer (score 3):

Open `geany.conf` in a different editor and set the line `reload_clean_doc_on_file_change=false` to `reload_clean_doc_on_file_change=true`

Comment: This worked for me. Now Geany automatically reloads the file without any message/warning.

Comment: Confirmed.  Edit->Preferences->Various. files.reload_clean_doc_on_file_change=true

Comment: repo source: https://github.com/geany/geany/blob/master/src/keyfile.c

Answer (score 0):

The dialog cannot be disabled and automatic reloading is not supported (which could be bad anyway, depending on whether you've made changes to the document).

That being said, I had started working on a better method using GtkInfoBar like Gedit uses so that it wouldn't block you from working but still notify you of changes. Unfortunately I haven't had much time or interest to push it through into the master branch. If you feel like trying to use it (not recommended in current out-of-date/incomplete state) or continuing work on it, [the branch is here](https://github.com/geany/geany/tree/document-messages).

Comment: Like other editors (Atom, VS Code, …) Geany could automatically reload the file if there have been no unsaved changes in the document before the reload.

Comment: Can't downvote (reputation), but this answer is wrong.

Comment: @ominug Irrelevant